# Zend Skeleton Tutorial

Tags: zend-framework2, skeleton-code

I'm very new to zend framework 2 and I've been reading the docs and absorbing it as best I can.

I'm working through the [zend skeleton tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html) and its all working but there's a minor point I don't understand.

In the album controller you're instructed to make a call to the table gateway to select all records - specifically  $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll().  But the method that gets called isn't one I've created so can someone explain how **getAlbumTable** resolves to what it does.  I would have expected to have called the serviceManager in the same way you call an invokable or factory - i.e. $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway')

Appreciate any advice you can give to a ZF2 newbie.

```
class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{

    protected $albumTable;


    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'albums' => $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll(),
        ));
    }
```

Comment: and where is your "getAlbumTable()" ?? IMHO ZF is overengineered. I am using cakephp in favor of zf now

Answer (score 0):

Did you skip a step? `$this->getAlbumTable()` (missing from the controller in your code) should return an instance of `AlbumTable`. This class (which you should have already created) has a `fetchAll()` method.

Take a look at the "Model files" section of the tutorial you linked to in your question: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#the-model-files

Comment: Sorry maybe I'm not explaining my question very well - the application all works fine. What I'm confused about is how can you make a call like $this->getAlbumTable() ?  Why does it not call it like $sm->get('AlbumTable') ?

Comment: I was being an idiot.  I neglected to spot I had copy and pasted another method into my controller which allowed me to get albumTable. Apologies!